# Different vertical line for each facet in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to display in each facet of a ggplot figure a vertical bar with the mean of the data in the facet. I can do this for an individual facet :

```
# For Petal Length Only :
Mean <- colMeans(iris["Petal.Length"])
iris %>% pivot_longer(cols = !Species,names_to = "Characteristic",values_to = "Value") %>% 
  filter(Characteristic=="Petal.Length") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Value,fill=Species))+geom_density()+facet_wrap(~Characteristic)+
geom_vline(xintercept = Mean)
```

But when doing it with facets, 4 vertical lines are displayed instead of one for each facet :

```
# For all characteristics :
Mean <- colMeans(iris[-5])
iris %>% pivot_longer(cols = !Species,names_to = "Characteristic",values_to = "Value") %>%
  

ggplot(aes(x=Value,fill=Species))+geom_density()+facet_wrap(~Characteristic)+geom_vline(xintercept = Mean)
# Display vertical lines for all means where I would like only one vertical bar
# by group displayed (one for petal length, one for sepal width, etc)
 
# for example for Petal Length, only the vertical line with intercept colMeans(iris["Petal.Length"]) should be displayed.
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue was with that 'Mean' variable. Its format is not consistent with primary dataset. Structure it in the same way and the faceting will work as expected.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
# For all characteristics :
Mean <- colMeans(iris[-5]) %>% as_tibble(rownames = "Characteristic")
iris %>% pivot_longer(cols = !Species,names_to = "Characteristic",values_to = "Value") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Value,fill=Species))+
  geom_density()+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = value),data=Mean) +
  facet_wrap(~Characteristic)
```